# Excel Pivot table grouping Row Labels that are Percentages

Tags: excel-2007, pivot-table

Here is my data (apologies for poor formatting, maybe that should have been my first question!):

```
Customer    Percentage Increase
1   2%
2   12%
3   -50%
4   87%
5   -20%
6   -1%
7   123%
8   -98%
9   10%
10  13%
```

I created a pivot table in Excel with Percentage Increase as the Row Labels and Count of Customer as the value.

```
    Row Labels  Count of Customer
-98%    1
-50%    1
-20%    1
-1% 1
2%  1
10% 1
12% 1
13% 1
87% 1
123%    1
Grand Total 10
```

I then wanted to group the percentages to something easier to read, but the percentage ranges do not show percentages, instead they show regular numbers.

```
Row Labels  Count of Customer
<-0.5   1
-0.5--0.25  1
-0.25-0 2
0-0.25  4
0.75-1  1
>1  1
Grand Total 10
```

How do I get the number formatting of my percentage ranges to be percentages, i.e. 0% - 25%, etc?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I know is to change them by hand, i.e., click into the cell with the label and change it to say what you want.

If you do this, I'd also create the labels for the categories that don't show up yet, e.g., 25% to 50% (and 50% to 75%) in your example.  To do this, choose Field Settings>Layout & Print and check "Show items with no data".  Change the labels for those ranges as well.  Once you do, you can uncheck "Show items with no data", and in the future if there are counts in new ranges the new labels will still be what you entered.  (At least it seems to work that way).

Comment: Thanks Doug. I guess that works ok if those will always be my groupings, e.g. 0-25%, 25%-50%, etc. However if later I would like to use 0-10%, 10%-20%, I will have to manually update the cells again. Cheers.